# Deleted mail needs to go to right deleted folder

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365

For work we have a personal o365 account and a couple shared 0365 accounts. I access all these accounts from the same outlook client.

When I delete a mail in one of the shared accounts it goes into my personal deleted folder instead of the deleted folder of the shared account. Because the accounts are shared my colleagues need to be able to see the deleted mails.

One of my colleagues managed to make it work for his account in the past, but he has no idea how he did it so he can't help me.

**How do I make the deleted mails go in the right account's deleted folder?**

I use outlook version 1803

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may refer to instructions in the link below to change the registry setting:
[Items that are deleted from a shared mailbox go to the wrong folder in Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/202517/items-that-are-deleted-from-a-shared-mailbox-go-to-the-wrong-folder-in).

Comment: One of the scripts on the page seems to work for me and some colleagues, thanks